# Apache Flink: Which method calls cause an execution?

Tags: apache-flink

I had to learn "the hard way" that using method calls like

```
someDataSet.collect()

someDataSet.count()
```

In the middle of your flink workflow should be avoided, as they cause a premature execution of the code. This of course is not what you want because of the lazy evaluation aproach that flink is taking. Are there any other method calls i should avoid because they do a executionEnvironment.execute() in the background?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, thanks :)

I looked at the source, and only `.count()` and `.collect()` call `.execute()`. But `.print()` and `.printToErr()` (and likely other print methods) call `.collect()`, so they also will trigger immediate execution.